# Multiple insertion with addition data with pg-promise

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

I have a large dataset that I want to insert into a postgres db, I can achieve this using pg-promise like this

```
function batchUpload (req, res, next) {
    var data = req.body.data;
    var cs = pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'], { table: 'customer' });
    var query = pgp.helpers.insert(data, cs);
    db.none(query)
    .then(data => {
        // success;

    })
    .catch(error => {
        // error;
        return next(error);
    });
}
```

The dataset is an array of objects like this:

```
           [
                {
                    firstname : 'Lola',
                    lastname : 'Solo',
                    email: 'mail@solo.com',
                },
                {
                    firstname : 'hello',
                    lastname : 'world',
                    email: 'mail@example.com',
                },
                {
                    firstname : 'mami',
                    lastname : 'water',
                    email: 'mami@example.com',
                }
            ]
```

The challenge is I have a column `added_at` which isn't included in the dataset and cannot be `null`. How do I add a timestamp for each record insertion to the query.

Comment: run ` alter table customer alter column added_at set default now();` or similar on db to set default for the column

Comment: @VaoTsun Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [ColumnConfig](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.ColumnConfig) syntax:

```js
const col = {
    name: 'added_at',
    def: () => new Date() // default to the current Date/Time
};
    
const cs = pgp.helpers.ColumnSet(['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', col], { table: 'customer' });
```

Alternatively, you can define it in a number of other ways, as [ColumnConfig](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.ColumnConfig) is very flexible.

Example:

```js
const col = {
    name: 'added_at',
    mod: ':raw', // use raw-text modifier, to inject the string directly
    def: 'now()' // use now() for the column
};
```

or you can use property `init` to set the value dynamically:

```js
const col = {
    name: 'added_at',
    mod: ':raw', // use raw-text modifier, to inject the string directly
    init: () => {
       return 'now()';
    }
};
```

See the [ColumnConfig](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/helpers.html#.ColumnConfig) syntax for details.

P.S. I'm the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).